# How to parse "There is no way + clause"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

I have read the following sentence in ***Diary of a Wimpy Kid 3***:

> ***There was no way*** I was going to break my honest streak over something as dumb as this.

Is "There was no way..." an existential sentence? How to parse this sentence construction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is an existential sentence; it is denying that any such **way** existed. **There was/is no way [that]** is a common English expression meaning that there are no circumstances that will cause something to come about.

English frequently omits the conjunction *that* in situations like this, though many other languages do not permit the omission (for example, *que* in Spanish must be included). In this sentence, **[that] I was going to break...** is a subordinate clause identifying what particular **way** does not exist.

Comment: What does " way " mean here?

Comment: @user48070 The expression **no way** is a common idiom meaning that something is impossible. See [the Idioms section in the OALD entry](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/way).

Comment: " [that] I was going to break... is a subordinate clause identifying what particular way does not exist. "As you mentioned, what kind of subordinate clause is it?

Comment: "Way" means "manner" here.

Comment: _There_-insertion following Adverb fronting produces this: _I was going to break ... dumb as this in no way_ ==> (Adverb fronting) ==> _In no way I was going ,,, dumb as this_ ==> (_There_-insertion) _There was no way that I was going ... dumb as this_.